# Web Api on Azure shows no error detail using 'return InternalServerError(ex)'

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, exception

My Web Api when run locally (in Release mode) will return any errors in this format:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "No text specified",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
    "StackTrace": null
}
```

But after deployment/publish to an Azure VM, only this remains:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

*API code:*

```
try
{
    var msg = ...
    new MessageService().SaveMessage(msg)); // <-- does some checks; may throw.
    return Ok();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return InternalServerError(ex);
}
```

I'd like it to be more detailed on Azure, like the local result.
Can this be achieved, and if so, how?

I already (temporarily) removed `<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />` from the `<system.web>` part of Web.Release.config, and then re-deployed, but that made no difference.

Or am I using the wrong approach/pattern?
Obviously technical details should be limited, but right now we get no details at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try adding the following to your Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

Note: I wouldn't recommend that you keep this setting on in a production environment.

Comment: I have added that to the Global.asax in my web api and published to Azure, but still I only receive "An error has occurred".  Is there anything else that might prevent the true error being returned?

Answer (score 5):

If instead you use

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Default;
```

then you can use the system.webServer error switch e.g.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough">
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Note the existingResponse attribute to preserve the error message.

Comment: your answer. I used your code verbatim, but continue to receive nondescript errors from web api methods. It seems like it should work, but it's not. There must be more to it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, the post is three years old, things have changed a little. If you setup a new Azure Mobile App with Visual Studio 2017 there is no longer a Global.asax.cs. I searched for hours, where to put this IncludeErrorDetailPolicy. It won't work without that setting.

You do it in your Startup.MobileApp.cs:

```
  public partial class Startup
  {
        public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);
```

Don't forget, in your Web.config you also need to set:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough">
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Don't use that for production environment!

Answer (score 2):

For Web API 2, you can implement a custom IExceptionLogger that utilizes Azure Application Insights. Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

namespace Your.Namespace.Here
{
    public class TelemetryExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

        public TelemetryExceptionLogger(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
            {
                telemetryClient.TrackException(context.Exception);
            }

            base.Log(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it with Web API:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;
using Your.Namespace.Here;

namespace Some.Other.Namespace.Or.The.Same
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // --- Normal Web API configuration here ---

            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new TelemetryExceptionLogger(new TelemetryClient())); 
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, you will need to have set up Application Insight in Azure and for your VS project, but that is a story for another time :)
For more information, see [Application Insights: Exception Telemetry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/12/12/application-insights-exception-telemetry.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have a scenario with the same error, and the problem was a copy&paste in the route header attribute of a method. I have the same route for two methods

```
    [Route("test/Method1")]
    public IHttpActionResult Method1(){...}

    [Route("test/Method1")]
    public IHttpActionResult Method2(){...}
```

Check the new methods and Routes added.