# Azure doesn't pass my custom message in HttpException

Tags: c#, azure, web-config

I have a REST API in an Azure WebApp.
When a POST is sent to my endpoint I do some checks and if needed I throw an HttpException:

```
throw new HttpException(400, msgInfo);
```

Where `msgInfo` is my custom message. In my dev-machine using Visual Studio 2015 my response is:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"[my custom message]","ExceptionType":"System.Web.HttpException","StackTrace":"..."}
```

Now I can show the user a useful message.

But on Azure the response is just:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

So no custom message.

Most likely this is a setting in Azure. I understand it should not show my full stack trace, but it should show `ExceptionMessage`.

In my `Web.config` I have:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Web API 2, you can try `return BadRequest("message");`

Comment: Thanks Martin for your suggestion. It is an older application and I can't use `BadRequest`, it's not recognized. So I assume it is before Web API v2.
Any other suggestions I could try. I tried adding `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />` but it didn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net web api has a separate configuration for how the error detail is shown in different environments.

In you `HttpConfiguration`, there is a property called `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy`. Here is its possible value.

```
public enum IncludeErrorDetailPolicy
{
    // Summary:
    //     Use the default behavior for the host environment. For ASP.NET hosting, usethe value from the customErrors element in the Web.config file. 
    //     For self-hosting, use the value System.Web.Http.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.LocalOnly.
    Default = 0,

    // Summary:
    //     Only include error details when responding to a local request.
    LocalOnly = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Always include error details.
    Always = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Never include error details.
    Never = 3,
}
```

You could configure as below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCloudServiceGateway();

        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always // Add this line to enable detail mode in release
        };
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430077/web-api-on-azure-shows-no-error-detail-using-return-internalservererrorex).

Also, you could set `<customErrors mode="Off"/>`, which specifies that custom errors are disabled. The [detailed ASP.NET errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx) are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

Comment: Thanks Joey. Adding `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always` solved my issue. I'll mark it as the answer.